# Javascript RegEx date validation text file

Tags: javascript, regex

Every new sentence starts with a date, so I want to split the text on date regEx

I've used this expression (which in my belief is right):

```
var date = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/;
```

The date always appears in this format and never is something else. Text file appears in this order:

10-05-13 16:14:49: Wence: Hey how you're doing?

10-05-13 16:14:52: Bas: Nothing much. How about you?

This code returns null, which is very odd and I can't find what i'm doing wrong since there isn't much to miss.

```
var chat = "10-05-13 16:14:49: Wence: Hey how you're doing?

10-05-13 16:14:52: Bas: Nothing much. How about you?"

var date = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/;
document.write(chat.match(date));
```

this, as well as this:

```
var  chat = "10-05-13 16:14:49: Wence: Hey how you're doing?

    10-05-13 16:14:52: Bas: Nothing much. How about you?"

var date = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/;
document.write(chat.split(date));
```

both return null.

Answer (score 3):

`\d{4}` is looking for four digits. But the year is saved as a two-digit number.

Try:

```
var date = /^(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/;
```

Comment: Thanks, very stupid not see that. Still, the split function doesn't split the entire date but rather the dates themself. it returns: "10,05,13" instead of ",10-05-13,"

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for 2 numbers, followed by a dash, then another 2 numbers, dash and then 4 numbers. The format of the dates is different. You are using 4 digits for the year in your regex but only 2 in the actual date. Changing the code to reflect that works

`/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/`